# Maven Jenkins autoupdate version within POM

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, nexus

is there a goal i can call on for maven to update the POM file version in regular increments every time i trigger a build?

```
<version>2.22.0.4</version>
```

updated to:

```
<version>2.22.0.5</version>
```

I know i can call the command -DdevelopmentVersion=2.22.0.5 to update to that version manually but i want maven to know that it should automatically adjust the POM file version tag by incrementing by 1 each time.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Maven versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) as part of your build invocation.

Answer (score 0):

This is my way to do this:

```
stage('Update version') {
        steps {
            script {
                //get current version from pom.xml
                JAR_FINAL_VERSION = sh (
                    script: 'mvn spring-boot:build-info | grep Building | awk \'{split(\$0,r," "); print r[4]}\'',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
                //get major version
                MAJOR_VERSION = sh (
                    script: "echo ${JAR_FINAL_VERSION} | awk '{split(\$0,r,\"-\"); print r[1]}' | awk '{split(\$0,r,\".\"); print r[1] \".\" r[2]}\' ",
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
                //get the minor version and +1
                UPDATED_VERSION = sh (
                    script: "echo ${JAR_FINAL_VERSION} | awk '{split(\$0,r,\"-\"); print r[1]}' | awk '{split(\$0,r,\".\"); print r[3]}' | awk '{value=1+\$1} END{print value}' ",
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()

                //update version
                sh "mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=${MAJOR_VERSION}.${UPDATED_VERSION}-SNAPSHOT"
                //git config 
                sh "git config user.email asher@runnable.run"
                sh "git config user.name asher"
                //checkout new branch, named your branch name
                sh "git checkout -b ${params.GIT_Branch}"
                sh "git commit -a -m 'Triggered Build: update pom version'"
                //push to github
                sh "git push -u origin ${params.GIT_Branch}"
            }
        }
    }
```

**Let me explain the above:**

First, we can use `mvn spring-boot:build-info` to get the pom version, and then filter out the desired information through the shell and assign it to `JAR_FINAL_VERSION`.

Then operate on `JAR_FINAL_VERSION`,
If `JAR_FINAL_VERSION=1.0.1`, then `MAJOR_VERSION` will be 1.0 , it can be made after executing the following command

```
  echo ${JAR_FINAL_VERSION} | awk '{split($0,r,"-"); print r[1]}' | awk '{split($0,r,"."); print r[1] "." r[2]}'
```

The same way gets the minor version and +1 , assigns it to `UPDATED_VERSION`, and implements it through the following command:

```
echo ${JAR_FINAL_VERSION} | awk '{split($0,r,"-"); print r[1]}' | awk '{split($0,r,"."); print r[3]}' | awk '{value=1+$1} END{print value}'
```

Next, we need to update the version in pom.xml, which can be achieved by command `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.2`

The last few steps are to configure git in the current Jenkins, and then submit and push to GitHub